# Crashlytics- Missing dYSM error

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I have integrated my iOS project with **Crashlytics** , i get Error "We are missing dYSM to process crashes" , i have added dYSM for my latest build but its not working , it keeps asking to show same issue . No help on "Crashlytics Support".Can anyone guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the process I needed in order to solve the same issue for myself. Hopefully it helps someone else.

**Make sure you have the proper dSYMs**

If you uploaded the app to the store using an archive, make sure you download the dSYMs

1. Go to `Window->Organizer` in Xcode
2. Find the Archive you used
3. Select the archive and click "Download dSYMs".

**Finding the UUID**

1. In Fabric you should see the "Missing dSYM" message. Click that, and you will see something like this below:

[image: Missing dSYM dialog in the Missing dSyms section of Fabric]
*(I've blacked out the UUID, but it should display the UUID in that box)*

If you do not see the missing dSYM Message, you can find it here.

1. Click on the gear on the top right of your Fabric Dashboard in your web browser.
2. Click on "Apps"
3. Click on your Application
4. On the right you should see "Missing DSYMs"

**Finding the dSYM associated with the UUID**

Copy the UUID from that message, and paste the following command into an open Terminal window:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == THE-UUID"
```

This will tell you where the dSYM file you need is located.

**Symbolicating the Crashes**

Upload the file that you just located in the missing dSYM page.

The crashes will take some time to symbolicate after this (for me it takes 5-10 minutes).

**Notes**

On iOS 9, if you're using Bitcode, you'll need to download the dSYMs from Xcode first.

If you upload the wrong file, it won't tell you. The "Missing dSYM" file message will just continue to show. You need to make sure you upload the right dSYM file in order to properly symbolicate.

For more information, go [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html) and read the official Fabric documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Crashlytics here.

If you click on alert from your dashboard, you'll be taken to your app's settings, where you can upload the missing dSYM zipped up. Just run a search in spotlight with the UDID given!

One thing to note, on iOS 9, if you're using Bitcode, you'll need to download the dSYMs from Xcode first.

Comment: Can you let me know what was unclear on my answer above?

Comment: i have found dSYM file , and uploaded, but still it keeps asking to upload it.my question was how to find right dSYM file .the answer you provided is not different from answer provided on crashlytics support

Comment: dSYM  file was not found.so i removed the app and again connected with crashlytics as new app.it fixed my issue .

Comment: Glad to hear you're all set! All the dSYMs should also be stored in XCode's Organizer if you can't find them via spotlight.

Comment: i tried to find id using spotlight and terminal.i did not succeed.so is removed and re uploaded the app.as app is not still on itunes store.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to find DYSM folder:

- open Xcode.
- Select window from the taskbar and select organizer option. It will open the archives that you have created.
- Right click on the archive and select show in finder. You will find a xarchive file. Right click on it and select show package content.
- There you will find the DYSM folder, ZIP it and upload It to firebase.